# Is there a way to use only the RUM features of New Relic?

Tags: javascript, perl, newrelic

I'm running a service built entirely with Perl which is not supported by New Relic (unless you run your app via ActiveState's hosting platform).

I'm interested in using >only< the RUM (real user monitoring - data gleaned from a javascript tracker) features of New Relic.  I could probably reverse engineer the API for this, but that sounds fairly brittle.  Is there a known safe way to take advantage of just this part of New Relic?

Comment: I wanted this too. Turns out there is a 'lite' version of the js.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

New Relic's RUM uses dynamic JavaScript snippets that are generated and injected by the New Relic Agent. Thus, you can't just copy/paste in static JS snippets (at least, it's not designed or intended to be used like that). The RUM footer dynamically identifies the web transaction, as well as time spent in the application and queue. You can read more about how RUM works here:

https://newrelic.com/docs/features/how-does-real-user-monitoring-work